# Default UIColor of iPhone Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, rgb, uicolor, navigationbar

Can anyone tell me the RGB for the default iPhone navigation bar blue? I know that you can normally set the default color by setting

```
self.navigationBarTintColor = nil;
```

However, that doesnt work in this case, so I need to set the exact blue.

Thanks for your answer,
Doonot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:0.33 brightness:0.69 alpha:0]` is a tint very close to the original -- I do see a slight difference though, when compared to the default.

Source: [What is the default color for navigation bar buttons on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905158/what-is-the-default-color-for-navigation-bar-buttons-on-the-iphone/906682#906682)

Answer (score 12):

You right : setting `tintColor property` to `nil` is the good way to set the default blue color.

But in order to set a `tintColor` you have to do like that :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;
```

Comment: No :) I am using the TTThumsViewController from the Three20 project, and afaik, the default color is black. So if I set it to nil, it will be black again (I tested it). So the only solution I think of is to set the color. Thx

Comment: Sorry if I say something wrong 'cause I didn't work yet with Three20 but TTThumsViewController seems to be a UIViewController subclass, you can't change the UINavigationBar tintColor thought an UIViewController but a UINavigationController or UINavigationBar subclass?

Answer (score 4):

I dont know whether this will help you or not. Worth a try.

Open the Digital Color Meter Application in you Mac.

Now Open a view controller in Interface Builder

Place The navigation Bar in the view controller

Move the Mouse to the Navigationbar

Now you can see the RGB value of the pixel that the mouse currently pointing to in the Digital Color meter Application.

use that RGB value in your UIColor

I know its weird. Just a thought.. Just a thought..

Answer (score 3):

1. create separate project, add `UINavigationBar` in interface builder with default tint color
2. write this code to get tint color `NSLog(@"tint color %@", navBar.tintColor);`
   you will see the result in log: 
        `tint color UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.121653 0.558395 0.837748 1`
3. set the tint color of any pannel you wish with this values: 
        `[navBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.121653f green:0.558395f blue:0.837748f alpha:1]];`

Answer (score 1):

> [UIColor colorWithRed:(247/255.0) green:(247/255.0) blue:(247/255.0)
>   alpha:1]

Answer (score 1):

```
// Set Appdelegate.m file
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self setCustomDesign];
}
-(void)setCustomDesign
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor :UI_DEFAULT_NAV_COLOR] ;
}
//Constant.h
#define UI_DEFAULT_NAV_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:5/255.0 green:123/255.0 blue:253/255.0 alpha:1.0f]
```